# Android - Clicking on notification doesn't lead to activity

Tags: android

I have a timer that creates a notification on completion. Clicking on the notification should lead to an activity called TimerActivity. I create a notification like this:

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(completeNotificationIcon)
.setContentTitle(completeNotificationTitle)
.setContentText(completeNotificationText)
.setTicker(completeNotificationTicker)
.setAutoCancel(true);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

The problem is the activity doesn't open, the notification just autocancels.

On further investigation, it's only TimerActivity that won't open like this. If I change the intent to open say SttingsActivity.class, it works as it should. TimerActivity in the manifest:

```
    <activity   
       android:name=".TimerActivity"
       android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/action_timer"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />           
    </activity>
```

But it's defined like any of these other activities that work/can be opened by clicking on a notification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804649/android-clicking-on-notification-doesnt-lead-to-activity#comment37259171_21805011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add the flag FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT to PendingIntent.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open an activity outside an activity 
you should set some flag on the intent to make it work properly. Try this code please and let me know

```
 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(completeNotificationIcon)
.setContentTitle(completeNotificationTitle)
.setContentText(completeNotificationText)
.setTicker(completeNotificationTicker)
.setAutoCancel(true);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
       notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);//single top to avoid                //creating many activity stacks queue
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Actually, this is some nonsense bug that happens with cached intents and app reinstalls. Google's incompetence strikes again... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61850 and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63236

Comment: No, the solution was to add the flag FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT to PendingIntent

Comment: @TimSim can you please post that as your answer and accept it. I have been looking for almost an hour for this answer and almost missed it in your comments.